# Simulate and handle ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM

Tags: javascript, networking, axios

I've got a customer-hosted prod env where ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM errors are thrown from time to time.
From some reason I don't see these errors handled in FE like the regular 400/500 errors.
We use [axios 0.25](https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/v0.25.0) to make requests and some simple logic around it.
So the things I am struggling with are:

1. Is there a way I can reproduce this issue locally?
2. How do the browser / JS code handle this kind of errors? Are they returned like normal errors (i.e. status code, error message etc.)?

Thanks!